# Option Strict disallows late binding using IEnumerable

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

```
Dim distinctJoints As IEnumerable
distinctJoints = From row In spotsTable.AsEnumerable()
                                        Group row By Key = row("FUNCJOINTCODE") Into Group
                                        Select Key, Group

_evaluatedJointsCount = (From row In spotsTable.AsEnumerable()
                        Group row By Key = row("FUNCJOINTCODE") Into Group
                        Select Key, Group).Count()

'Process each joint
For Each currentJoint In distinctJoints
    Dim currentJointKey As String = currentJoint.Key
```

---

For the above code `currentJoint.Key` is showing error of late binding after option strict is on.
Could you please help me out of this.

Comment: No it doesn't. You used the wrong type - IEnumerable isn't the same as IEnumerable<T>. In this case there's no reason to define `distinctJoints` separately, just write `Dim DistinctJoins = From ...` and type inference will use the correct type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*First, let me congratulate your for moving your code towards `Option Strict On`! It might be some work in the beginning, but it pays off in the long run since a lot of errors will be found at compile-time rather than at run-time.*

That said, let's look at your problem. Here:

```
Dim distinctJoints As IEnumerable
```

you declare `distinctJoints` as a non-generic `IEnumerable`. A non-generic IEnumerable returns items of type `Object` when iterated over. The type `Object` does not contain a `Key` method. This is why you get a compile-time error.

Since your LINQ query returns a generic IEnumerable of an anonymous type, the solution is to use *type inference* instead. Activate `Option Infer On` (if you have not already done so) in your project properties and let the compiler infer the correct data type:

```
' Dim distinctJoints As IEnumerable <-- remove this
Dim distinctJoints = From row In spotsTable.AsEnumerable()
                     Group row By Key = row("FUNCJOINTCODE") Into Group
                     Select Key, Group
```

Comment: Thank you

there is also one issue whith below code and if I tried to remove Ienumearable from parameter then it gives error on "spot1.row("XUNIT")"

Private Sub EvaluateDistanceBetweenIrregularSpots(irregularWeldspots As IEnumerable)  
For Each spot1 In irregularWeldspots
If spot1.row("XUNIT") Is Nothing Then Continue For...

Comment: @PrasadK: I'm not sure I understand the problem from your comment. Please create a [mcve] and post a new question for that.